# JNDI Authentciation fails in plain java class but passes in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap, jndi

This might sound silly but I am encountering this behavior. I am using JNDI for LDAP authentication. I have a demo program setup, where the authentication fails upon providing incorrect credentials, but the same seems to go through in a Spring controller method(I'm making a post call from a react app).

**Plain Java implementation**

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties environment = new Properties();
        String userDomain = "@region.company.net";
        environment.setProperty(DirContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        environment.setProperty(DirContext.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://region.company.net:3268");
        environment.setProperty(DirContext.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        environment.setProperty(DirContext.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "userId"+userDomain);
        environment.setProperty(DirContext.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "wrongPassword");

        try {
            DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(environment);
            System.out.println("Authentication Successful !!!\n\n");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Authentication Failed !!!\n\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Controller implementation**

```
@PostMapping("/authenticateUser")
    public String authenticateUser(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> user) {
        Properties environment = new Properties();
        String userDomain = "@region.company.net";
        environment.setProperty(DirContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        environment.setProperty(DirContext.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://region.company.net:3268");
        environment.setProperty(DirContext.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    //  environment.setProperty(DirContext.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "userId"+userDomain);
        environment.setProperty(DirContext.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "wrongPassword");

        try {
            DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(environment);
            System.out.println("Authentication Successful !!!\n\n");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Authentication Failed !!!\n\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Method executed successfully";
        
    }
```

After providing incorrect password, if I execute this code then it prints `Authentication Failed !!!` which is expected, but when I insert this same code in a controller's method, it prints `Authentication Successful !!!`.

Shouldn't both behave in the same way? I find this behavior pretty weird. Perhaps, I am overlooking something?

**EDIT 1 : START**

It appears the line that sets the `SECURITY_PRINCIPAL` was commented out in case of the Spring Controller. I have commented out that part of code.
This now gives rise to another question as to why it never threw any exception ?
Not sure if I should ask this in a separate post.

Is it a proper way to authenticate by passing `Username`(like abc@xyz.com) as `SECURRITY_PRINCIPAL` or one should pass the entry path ?

**EDIT 1 : END**

Comment: Do you have any JNDI configurations in your `application.properties` file when running Spring scenario?

Comment: I just updated the OP. There was this silly mistake.